# rails ActiveRecord find in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When I'm in the Rails 3.2 console, I can do this just fine:

```
p = Person.last
p.last_name
```

and it prints the last name.

But when I try to find it by the `id`, it's able to locate the single
record and store it in my variable `p`, but I can't print the `last_name`
column. For example:

```
p = Person.where(id: 34).limit(1)
```

printing `p` here shows all the columns but `p.last_name` says this

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `last_name' for
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000000055f8840>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

A `where` query will return an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), which sort of acts like an array, even if you limit the number of returned records.

If you instead change your query to:

```
p = Person.where(id: 34).first
```

it will work as you want, and arel knows to automatically limit the query to a single result, so you don't have to explicitly specify `limit(1)`.

You could also change to either

```
p = Person.find(34) # Throws an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception if Person with id 34 does not exist
```

or

```
p = Person.find_by_id(34) # Returns nil if Person with id 34 does not exist. Does *not* throw an exception.
```

and it will return a single record as expected.

EDIT: A where query returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, as [@mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) mentioned in comments.

Comment: Yes, true, but I didn't want to confuse the situation further.

Comment: p = Person.find_by_id(34) for the win. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This returns a collection of active record objects:

```
p = Person.where(id: 34).limit(1)
```

But there's only one with id = 34, so it's a collection of 1.

The way to do this is:

```
p = Person.where(id: 34).limit(1).first
```

or, better:

```
p = Person.where(id: 34).first
```

or, even better:

```
p = Person.find(34)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably actually looking for is

```
@person = Person.find(34)
@person.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case Person is a class and it is inherited from ApplicationRecord

```
p = Person.where(id:10).limit(1)
```

It returns just the result of the query not the object.

You can check it by using

```
p.class # => It reurns Nilclass which means its not at all a class
```

So you cannot use p.last_name or p.first_name on p.