# Rails 4 undefined method 'to_key'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to update the attributes of an existing client in postgresql. I want to search for a client name, then store that info in a cookie and redirect to the form. If I use

```
@client = Client.first
```

my code works fine. Everything is loaded up and I can update, however I want it to be something like

```
@client = Client.where(:id => 1)
```

This works in rails console but it does not work when in the view or the controller. I end up with the error [image: Shitty rails error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
client = Client.find(1)
```

Or this:

```
client = Client.find_by(id: 1)
```

You can find more information about this in the Rails Guide section called [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html%20%E2%80%93%20%20nikkypx)

Alternatively (according to another answer on this site: [rails ActiveRecord find in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661586/rails-activerecord-find-in-console)) I think this would work (although I haven't personally tried it):

```
c = Client.where(id: 1).first
```

Comment: that is link to rails 2.3 guides, here is what you want http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks - will `find_by(id: 1) ` work? I believe this is the hash syntax for Ruby 2+

Answer (score 1):

```
@client = Client.find(1) # or Client.find_by(:id => 1)
```